# PHP compare 2 arrays and get only the non matching values

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays I want to get the values that are not the same but for some reason this is not working:

```
$newArray = array_unique(array_merge($array1, $array2)

var_dump(array1) = array(3) { [0]=> string(17) "verbal aggression" [1]=> string(19) "physical aggression" [2]=> string(3) "vol" }

var_dump(array2) = array(2) { [0]=> string(17) "verbal aggression" [1]=> string(19) "physical aggression" }
```

So I suspect $newArray to be:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "vol"" }
```

Comment: What about using [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) ?

Comment: ^ This is all what you need.

Comment: [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**array_diff** — Computes the difference of arrays

```
$array1 = array("verbal aggression", "physical aggression", "vol");
$array2 = array("verbal aggression", "physical aggression");

$result=array_diff($array1,$array2);
print_r($result);
```

**Output :**

```
Array
(
    [2] => vol
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the difference between two arrays you can use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) as suggested by @Sunil. But that finds only the elements that are in `$array1` but not in `$array2`.

If you want to find differences use the function below. This will also find elements that are in `$array2` but not in `$array1`

```
function differences($array1, $array2){
    return array_merge(array_diff($array1,$array2),array_diff($array2,$array1));
}
```

Comment: Well Done... :)